# Основы ООП.C#. Virtual , override

Tags: c#, ооп

При создании класса на C# , появилась проблема.Как я понял , virtual с override нужны для разной реализации одного же метода. Так вот , я создал программу

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace nomid
{
    class me
    {
        public int age;
        public string name;
        public bool grandparents;
        public string pet;
        public int marks;
        public int grands;

        public me()
        {
            age = 0;
            name = "None";
            grandparents = false;
            pet = "None";
            marks = 0;
            About();
        }
        public me(int age, string name, bool grandparents, string pet)
        {
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
            this.grandparents = grandparents;
            this.pet = pet;
            About();
        }
        public virtual void About()
        {



            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name);
            Console.WriteLine("Age: " + age);
            Console.WriteLine("GrandParents: " + grandparents);
            Console.WriteLine("Pet: " + pet);
            if (marks <= 1)
            {
                marks = 2;
            }
            if (marks > 12)
            {
                marks = 12;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Middle grands: " + marks);
        }
        public me(int age, string name, bool grandparents,int grands)
        {
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
            this.grandparents = grandparents;
            this.marks = grands;
            About();
        }


    }
    class sister : me
    {



        public int course;
        //private string hi = "А я новый объект класса sister!";
        //private string info = "У меня есть  аргументы,которые принимаються через класс me";
        /*
        public sister()
        {
            About2();
        }
       */
        public override void About()
        {
            base.About();
            Console.WriteLine("Course: " + course);

        }
        public sister(int age,string name,bool grandparents,int grands,int course):base(age,  name, grandparents , grands) // Наследование спомощью base 
        {

            this.course = course;
            About();

        }

        /*
        public void About2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(hi);
            Console.WriteLine(info);
            Console.WriteLine("Также у меня есть свои аргументы,обьекты." );

            Console.WriteLine("Course:" + course);
        }
        */
    }
class MyBigClass
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Укажите возраст:");
            int x = Convert.ToInt32((Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.WriteLine("Укажите имя:");
            string x2 =  Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Укажите вашу середню оценку:");
            int x3 = Convert.ToInt32((Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.WriteLine("============================================");
            me Taras = new me(x,x2, false, x3);
            Console.WriteLine("============================================");
            //List<me> Dasha = new List<me>();
            //Dasha.Add(new sister());
            Console.WriteLine("Укажите возраст:");
            x = Convert.ToInt16((Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.WriteLine("Укажите имя:");
            x2 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Укажите вашу середню оценку:");
            x3 = Convert.ToInt16((Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.WriteLine("Укажите ваш курс:");
            int x4 = Convert.ToInt16((Console.ReadLine()));
            sister Dasha = new sister(x, x2, false, x3,x4);
            Console.WriteLine("============================================");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Она имеет класс о информации о мне и сестры , но при этом у сестры ещё добавляется курс(course) , и при вызове About выводится данные которые есть у обоих сторон  и ещё выводится course.Но выводится это всё  не так как я думал .

```
Укажите возраст:
10000
Укажите имя:
TozeXz
Укажите вашу середню оценку:
143
Укажите ваш курс:
4
Name: TozeXz
Age: 10000
GrandParents: False
Pet:
Middle grands: 12
Course: 0
Name: TozeXz
Age: 10000
GrandParents: False
Pet:
Middle grands: 12
Course: 4
```

Почему выводится сначала выводятся все значения нормально кроме course(почему равно 0), а потом все значение выводятся нормально ( все значения соответствуют значениям которые я им передал ) ? Как исправить код так , что бы выводился текст 1 раз , без проблема с информацией которое я ей задал ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё абсолютно верно работает. С созданием класса `me` вроде бы все понятно. Он работает так как задумывалось.
Давайте рассмотрим поведение класса `sister`. При создание унаследованного класса сначала будет вызван конструктор базового класса .(В конструкторе класса `sister` вы даже вызываете конструктор базового класса явно). 
Теперь в этом конструкторе базового класса при создании класса `sister` вы сначала присваиваете поля базового класса,  а потом вызываете метод `About()`. Метод `About()` виртуальный, значит будет вызвана реализация метода для производного класса (которая выводит еще и курс). Но в момент создания базового класса никакое поле `course` ещё не инициализировано (а будет инициализировано позже в конструкторе производного класса). Таким образом в качестве значения выведется значение полученное при создании (0).
А потом будет исполнен конструктор производного класса, который присвоит поле `course` и также вызовет метод `About()`. Вот и второй вызов этого метода. Но к этому моменту поле `course` уже вполне корректно установлено.

Чтобы исправить советую отказаться от практики вызывать в конструкторе всякие побочные методы. И вызывать для каждого класса `About()` после его полного создания отдельно.

Comment: разве не для этого и нужны virual и override?

Comment: @True-hacker не очень понимаю о чем вы. Они отлично выполняют свою функцию. `virtual` показывает, что при работе с классом стоит найти нужную реализацию функции в таблице виртуальных методов. `override` показывает, что это не отдельная новая (`new`) функция, а перегрузка виртуальной функции из базового класса.

Comment: @True-hacker Собственно тут как раз `About()` и ведет себя как положено виртуальной функции. И из конструктора базового класса вызывает метод `About()` производного (который с `course`).